# Setup port mirorring on Sonos speakers

Tags: sonos

I'd like to capture the traffic sent by a Sonos speaker (to troubleshoot streaming issues).
I've found one way to do this but it's a bit cumbersome: I plug the Sonos speaker via an ethernet to usb adapter to my PC, share the PC connection and then capture on that interface.
It's limited to one speaker and if the speaker has ever been configured to use the WiFi, it seems that it uses WiFi even plugged that way (and I don't capture anything).

What's the detailed setup to use port mirorring to do this? I'd like to compare the two solutions and don't know much about port mirorring setup.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend getting yourself a network hub to plug Sonos and the computer into and capture from that.

Comment: Thanks, is there a specific hub you'd recommend? I've been having a look around but there are a lot of offers for potentially way more complicated scenarios so I found it hard to choose a simple, cheap one that would do that basic scenario.